# Pattern matching algorithm with rotation considerations

Tags: computer-vision, pattern-matching

I have a map that looks like the following. I have extracted edges from a given observation image. I wish to rotate this edge and somehow match it with the map. Is there any established algorithm in computer vision or any geometric method, that matches a small image inside a big image, and takes into consideration image transformations especially rotation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What should the match actually be in this case? I don't even know how to manually match it, how should the computer know in this case?

Comment: The match would be like, since I'm seeing a corner in the filter, I would manually label places near corners in the map.

Comment: Which corners should it match though? All of them? Only ones where the sides are equal to those lengths? Please give a full description with examples of the exact output you *want*.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any established algorithm in computer vision or any geometric method, that matches a small image inside a big image, and takes into consideration image transformations especially rotation

Take a look at [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) (short for scale-invariant feature transform). It is robust against both scale and rotation, well established and widely used. You could extract key points from your image and try to match those in your other image.

You should try if it works well for your application, but from your description alone it might be what you are looking for.